# Anchor jumps too far

Tags: html, anchor

I have some anchor links in my One-Page Website, and I have a problem with only one of them.

The section is inside a div where I have a title and a button.

When I click the anchor link it jumps too far, specifically to the button (under the title) and not to the head of the section (before the title).

Anchor link: (The issue is with the 4th link `"#solution"`)

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse  collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right scroll">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#works">Media</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#solutions">Solutions</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#partners">Partners</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The section code:

```html
<div id="solutions">
    <h2 class="text-center  wowload fadeInUp">solutions bla bla bla</h2>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='pages/solutions.html'" class="blue_button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: From a brief look through, that should work. Can you provide a small working page which reproduces the problem?

Comment: I'd make a guess at some Javascript overriding an action or another element has an ID of 'solutions'. The HTML looks fine, apart from the inline Javascript

Comment: the other links working very well though, i checked and no other elements has the same ID, i even changed the ID name and still with the same issue. - i have a limited knowlage with coding so maybe i didn't undesrtod your answer well.

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/978gcy3b/] don't get any problem click about and solutions from nav . if possible add css also. :)

Comment: the link you provided is not working, anyway, the about link and all the other works fine, only the solution link is jumping too far.

Comment: [UPDATE]  i fix it by adding padding-top in CSS,

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/978gcy3b/ ] sorry my bad the ] attached with the link

Comment: This problem is even worse if you have some kind of zindex header or navbar, the title of the anchor might be completely covered by the header. Padding is not really a solution, because you would have to pad all anchors to be bigger than the header, etc.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by adding {padding-top: 6em;} in CSS